# How to obtain the hidden layer sizes from HyperoptEstimator?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, hyperopt

I am trying to use the hyperopt-sklearn library to get the best hyperparameters from a multilayer perceptron. The documentation is scarce and most of the answers seem hidden between layers and layers of code. Many of these lines, surpass my coding understanding.

I defined a space for the Hyperopt estimator, however, I have not come to find the correct function to get which was the selected configuration for layers and neurons. The ".best_model()" method outputs other relevant parameters, but not the ones I am looking for. For example:

```
>>> print(mlp_clf.best_model())
```

```
... {'learner': MLPClassifier(activation='tanh', alpha=0.005856877343088139,
              beta_1=0.846494371322821, beta_2=0.9945077173668336,
              epsilon=4.015091558071884e-06, learning_rate='adaptive',
              learning_rate_init=0.0942011641931547, max_fun=28556,
              max_iter=286, momentum=0.9551365399897995,
              power_t=0.13309940833978537, random_state=0,
              tol=0.008930401946599196,
              validation_fraction=0.16933029546511605), 'preprocs': (PCA(n_components=18, whiten=True),),      'ex_preprocs': ()}
```

My current code is:

```
clf = mlp_classifier(hp.choice('number_of_layers',[
                                                        {"1layer": scope.int(hp.qloguniform("1.1", np.log(1), np.log(1000), 1))},
                                                        {"2layer": [scope.int(hp.qloguniform("1.2", np.log(1), np.log(1000), 1)), 
                                                                    scope.int(hp.qloguniform("2.2", np.log(1), np.log(1000), 1))]},
                                                        {"3layer": [scope.int(hp.qloguniform("1.3", np.log(1), np.log(1000), 1)), 
                                                                    scope.int(hp.qloguniform("2.3", np.log(1), np.log(1000), 1)), 
                                                                    scope.int(hp.qloguniform("3.3", np.log(1), np.log(1000), 1))]}
                                                        ]))
mlp_clf = HyperoptEstimator(classifier= clf,
                            algo=tpe.suggest, 
                            max_evals=20, trial_timeout=200,seed=np.random.seed(42),
                            n_jobs=-1,verbose=True)
mlp_clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

I acknowledge that perhaps the estimator is just getting one option, given a bad implementation of the `hp.choice`, still, I'd even appreciate that remark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the hyperparameter space for `MLPClassifier` in `hpsklearn` [here in the source code](https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt-sklearn/blob/a84603c5232e01a9edda961d9f8aba6ea0f3038a/hpsklearn/components/neural_network/_multilayer_perceptron.py#L155).  The hyperparameter names match those of `sklearn`'s `MLPClassifier`, so you can review [their documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html) for the formats those are expected to take.  At the least, you need your space to name `hidden_layer_sizes`, not `number_of_layers` and `1layer` etc.

The hpsklearn object has an attribute `trials` which should contain the hyperopt `Trials`, which maybe will show the hyperparameters as you pass them.
I guess hyperparameters that sklearn doesn't actually accept (like `number_of_layers`) just get discarded?

Comment: It is working! I corrected the syntax, then realized that the .best_model() method gives you a dictionary. Using .get("learner") I accessed the estimator and then used all the attributes and methods from scikit-learn!